# Using structures in C with user defined functions

Tags: c, structure, user-defined-functions

I had came across a problem that I have tried so many times with different ways but still not able to obtain the required solution please do help me.
PROBLEM: Define a structure to store students’ details. Pass them to a function where the student with HIGHEST CGPA is calculated from a set of 5 students. And display the result.(Here we have to store name, age and CGPA obtained of each student)
Here is my try at the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void highCGPA(float b,struct detst D[4]);

struct detst
{
    int age;
    float CGPA;
    char name[30];
};

int main()
{
    struct detst D[4];
    int i;
    float h;
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
    printf("Enter the name of student %d:\n",i+1);
    scanf("%s",&D[i].name);
    printf("Enter the age of student %d:\n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&D[i].age);
    printf("Enter the CGPA obtined by student %d:\n",i+1);
    scanf("%f",&D[i].CGPA);
    }
    highCGPA(h,D);
}

void highCGPA(float b,struct detst D[4])
{
    int i,max;
    
    max = D[0].CGPA;
    
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        if(D[i].CGPA > max)
        {
            max = D[i].CGPA;
        }
    }
    printf("Highest CGPA obtained is:\n%f",max); 
}
```

Comment: `i <= 4` ?? Probably should think about making this `i <  4`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one problem. You're trying to store the data of 5 students in an array of struct with size 4. So:

```
struct detst D[5]; // fixed size
int i;
float h;
for(i=0;i<5;i++) { // EDIT (comments suggestion): for loop fix following standard convetions
    /* take input */
}
```

Lastly, if you declare `max` as an `int`, you can't try to print it with a format specifier for `float`. So:

```
printf("Highest CGPA obtained is: %d\n",max); // format specifier for int is %d (not %f)
```

Comment: Are you sure he wants 5 students? Your `for`-loop still doesn't follow standard conventions. `max` should probably be defined as `float` rather than  changing the format specifier. (`max` is used as the maximum value of `CGPA`, which is `float`)

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I have made the required changes in my code and now it is working alright. Thanks you for saving me.

Comment: @HAL9000 He literally said the function takes a "set of 5 students". Considering the little information about how the desired output format should be I can't know if it's better to change max to float or viceversa CGPA to int. And I left the for loop like it was in the example, since it wasn't strictly required for fixing his problem.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that he wanted 5 students. The issue with the `max` variable, and more importantly, the `for` loop still stands. When copying bad code in your answer, you should at leas give a small comment to why this is bad. In this case the code confuses  readers to what should be an aprpriate fix.

Comment: I agree with the `for` part. But I still think that since we don't know how he wants the output we can't tell if it's `max` that should be changed to `float` or `CGPA` to `int`. Probably I should have at least specified that one or the other fix should be made.

Comment: If you don't know if something should be `float` or `int` its is better to ask for more info rather than providing something that is likely a wrong fix. (`CGPA` is used as `float` everywhere else in the program)

Comment: For the output all I want is the highest `CGPA` from the array in `float` so I guess there is no need of conversion of float `CGPA` to `int`.

Comment: Then if your highest value is `60,3` and you want it printed with `float` precision instead of `60` you should actually change `max` to `float` and revert the fix you did on the printf (keep the `%f`) like others were saying. My solution approximate the values because you print an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of other problems.

1. your declaration of funtion `highCGPA` is above your `struct detst` definition
   you should have got error

> error: array type has incomplete element type ‘struct detst’

declare your function after the structure definition.

2. your `max` variable is `int` in the function `highCGPA` , but you are trying to store a `float` value in it.

Comment: I am using DEV C++ as my editor and compiler so I am not facing any errors while declaration of highCGPA above struct detst also I think if you declare in such way, you are declaring it globally, that is, the USER DEFINED FUNCTION can be used anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

With a sligth change to program functionallity can be improved:

```c
#include <float.h> // FLT_MAX
#include <stdio.h>

struct detst
{
   int age;
   float CGPA;
   char name[30];
};

// Return offset of student with highest CGPA
int highCGPA(struct detst const (*D)[5]);  // Using pointer to array 
                                           // to avoid degeneration

int main()
{
   struct detst D[5];
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      printf("Enter the name of student %d:\n", i + 1);
      scanf("%29s", D[i].name);  // Make sure we don't overwrite the buffer
      printf("Enter the age of student %d:\n", i + 1);
      scanf("%d", &D[i].age);
      printf("Enter the CGPA obtained by student %d:\n", i + 1);
      scanf("%f", &D[i].CGPA);
   }
   int bestStudentOffset = highCGPA(&D); // By asking for best student
                                         // we can obtain a lot more
   printf(
      "Best student is %d year old %s with\n",
      D[bestStudentOffset].age,
      D[bestStudentOffset].name);
   printf("Highest CGPA obtained is:\n%f\n", D[bestStudentOffset].CGPA);
}

// Return offset of student with highest CGPA
int highCGPA(struct detst const (*D)[5])
{
   int i, maxOffset = -1;
   float max = -FLT_MAX;

   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      if((*D)[i].CGPA > max)
      {
         max       = (*D)[i].CGPA;
         maxOffset = i;
      }
   }
   return maxOffset;
}
```